# how to render google map with dark theme... ? i am using vuejs

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, vue.js, google-maps-api-3

i need to render google map with dark theme... when i add json value from mapstyle in my code it will show dark them for 2 seconds,after that it returns to normal map style. below i have given code..

i have given both html and script below... when i run below code dark them will display for 1 or 2 sec again it goes back to normal google map.

//html tag

```
           <va-card type="plain"  >
            <div id="map" style="height:90vh;width:auto;" />
          </va-card>
```

//below is my script

```
              let mapOptions = {
                 zoom:12,
                 center: new google.maps.LatLng( 12.9716, 77.5946),
                 scrollwheel: true,
                 style:                     [
                      {
                        "elementType": "geometry",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#212121"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "elementType": "labels.icon",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "visibility": "off"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#757575"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#212121"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "administrative",
                        "elementType": "geometry",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#757575"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "administrative.country",
                        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#9e9e9e"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "visibility": "off"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "administrative.locality",
                        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#bdbdbd"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "poi",
                        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#757575"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "poi.park",
                        "elementType": "geometry",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#181818"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "poi.park",
                        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#616161"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "poi.park",
                        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#1b1b1b"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "road",
                        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#2c2c2c"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "road",
                        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#8a8a8a"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "road.arterial",
                        "elementType": "geometry",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#373737"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "road.highway",
                        "elementType": "geometry",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#3c3c3c"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
                        "elementType": "geometry",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#4e4e4e"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "road.local",
                        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#616161"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "transit",
                        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#757575"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "water",
                        "elementType": "geometry",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#000000"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "water",
                        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#3d3d3d"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
              }; 


              let map = new window.google.maps.Map(
                document.getElementById("map"),
                mapOptions
              );
```

Comment: quick search on google docs : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

Comment: use "styles" instead of "style"

Comment: ya ,i tried but its not working bro..

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `styles` property. Here's a [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hLe1psrf/) that shows a dark-colored map. Full code in vanilla JS below:

```
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 8,
    styles: [{
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#212121"
        }]
      },
      {
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      },
      {
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#757575"
        }]
      },
      {
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#212121"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#757575"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative.country",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#9e9e9e"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
        "stylers": [{
          "visibility": "off"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "administrative.locality",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#bdbdbd"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#757575"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.park",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#181818"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.park",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#616161"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.park",
        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#1b1b1b"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#2c2c2c"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#8a8a8a"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#373737"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#3c3c3c"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#4e4e4e"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "road.local",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#616161"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#757575"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#000000"
        }]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [{
          "color": "#3d3d3d"
        }]
      }
    ]
  });
}
```

Hope this helps!